# Joomla and Eventbrite Integration

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, module, plugin, custom-component

I am looking for a way to integrate [Eventbrite](http://www.eventbrite.co.uk/) with Joomla. I want to show a list of upcoming events that I have created. There are a number of default widgets available with Eventbrite (copy / paste html code) but they are pretty basic, so I think i'll have to create some sort of custom component / plugin using their [API](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api).

I'm not sure where to start with this development, and was wondering if anyone had similar experience, or can point me in the right direction. I've been experimenting with their API (using the Postman app) and I am able to retrieve a list of events using the following API endpoint

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/events?token=mytoken
```

This returns a JSON list of events and details. I'm not sure how I take this and integrate it with Joomla though. Ideally I would like to be able to create a new module (Upcoming Events), and display this on various pages throughout my site.

There appears to be a lot of WP plugins available for Eventbrite, the only Joomla one I could find is called [Combrite](http://combrite.com/) - although every time I enter my email address to receive the download link it never arrives.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A slimmed down version of what I use for my module: https://pastebin.com/AXV03VkK

Comment: Thanks for this @Lodder This is very helpful, I was almost there. I should be able to build on your sample code. I'll need to add additional logic to deal with limiting events and only displaying the necessary details I require. Is it now just a matter of me creating a custom module, packaging it, and uploading to Joomla? All new to me :)

Comment: Yeah the first module I made that fetched data from an API was a bit iffy at first for me. But once you've done one, it's easy after that. Hopefully you decide to use Javascripts fetch() method in the future once you feel more comfortable with APIs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Lodder for providing the code below which is very helpful

```
<?php
 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
 
use Joomla\CMS\Http\HttpFactory;
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;
 
class ModFooHelper
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->baseurl = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/events?token=mytoken';
    }
 
    public static function getEvents()
    {
        $httpOptions = [
            'userAgent' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17\r\n"
        ];
 
        $options = new Registry($httpOptions);
        $http    = HttpFactory::getHttp($options);
        $httpResult = $http->get($this->baseurl);
 
        $results = json_decode($httpResult->body);
 
        return $results;
    }
}
```